# Constraint Layout child goes offscreen

Tags: android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout, android-11

Constraints of ConstraintLayout Behaves something different. Contraint **bottom to bottom of parent behave like bottom to top of parent and End to end of the parent behave like End to Start of parent**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.splash.SplashScreen">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/hiranya_red"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Bottom to Bottom of parent]

and if I set like this

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
```

[image: Bottom to Top of parent]

Dependencies and Config Version:

> ```
>     minSdkVersion = 21
>     targetSdkVersion = 30
>     compileSdkVersion = 30
>
>     // App dependencies
>     appCompatVersion = "1.2.0"
>     constraintLayoutVersion = "2.0.0"
>     coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9"
>     dataStoreVersion = "1.0.0-alpha04"
>     espressoVersion = "3.3.0"
>     fragmentVersion = "1.3.0-beta01"
>     gradleVersion = '4.1.1'
>     hiltAndroidXVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"
>     hiltVersion = "2.28.3-alpha"
>     junitVersion = "4.13.1"
>     kotlinVersion = "1.4.20"
>     ktxVersion = "1.3.2"
>     lifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
>     materialVersion = "1.3.0-alpha04"
>     navigationVersion = "2.3.1"
>     retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"
>     roomVersion = "2.2.5"
>     testExtJunitVersion = "1.1.2"
> ```

Comment: It's not reproducable may be caused due to IDE errors .. I recommed you to invalidate caches/ restart android studio once

Comment: Hi @AgentP thank you for your suggestion. Invalidate cache & restart doesn't works, and Rebuild Project worked for me.